# Problems supporting iPhone 5 screen with Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, ios7, iphone-5, xcode5

I port some of my apps with the new Xcode to 64-bit, I'm now also use asset catalog to select the launch image.

Problem is that when submitting one of the targets to Apple I get this in email:
"Phone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. New iPhone apps and app updates submitted targeting iOS 6 and above must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the  portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images"

The problem wasn't there when I used Xcode 4.6 moreover, the app works pretty well on iPhone 5 with iOS7 and in simulator on iPhone 5 screen using iOS6 & iOS 7. So I can't figure our where it comes from.

Asset catalog of course pointing to the "Default-568h@2x.png" which is on the root folder of the projects (Other targets on the same project works fine). I've also checked that this file is on "Copy Bundle Resources".

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I also received this email after converting my project to use the asset catalog. I had deleted the original Default images from the root folder, and allowed them to only reside inside the asset catalog folder. What fixed the issue for me was putting the images back inside the root folder. Obviously they are duplicated now, but it did fix the issue for me. I assume that it is an Xcode bug causing the issue, so you could try removing and reinserting your Default images to see if that'll fix it.

Comment: are you sure you can use the assets new functionality with iOS 6 without receiving an error? I suppose that just iOS 7 projects will work with that new stuff. BTW the launch images and the icons are sensitive. If you put them inside folders the verification after uploading the app will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload app in iTune than put your iPhone 5 means 4 inch screen shots and you can used xCode 4.6 but this version not supported 4 inch xib than you can used xCode 5 and you can optimize your code in xCode 5 than you can submit your app in iTune.